# how to use mutex in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I changed my project from visual studio 2012 to 2010. But mutex is not working in visual studio 2010. In MSDN page it was mentioned that VC++10 doesn't support mutex. Is it possible to install any VC++11 as a separate package in visual studio 2010? or Could i use any third party mutex libraries? Please guide me.

Comment: Why would you change a project from 2012 to 2010? Boost.Thread if you really have to.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz My BOSS only has 2010 in his old laptop. And he is reluctant to migrate to new IDE. Simply saying - "MY Fate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is based on [`boost::mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) from the [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html) library. You could [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/) and [build](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/build.html) Boost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To add your answer, I found pthread also offers mutex. I used pthread and it worked fine:)

Comment: pthread is c, not c++; and indead pthread is a great threading library